# Swift JSON apostrophe ' string interpreted strangely on web server

Tags: json, swift, spring-mvc

`POST` a string to an endpoint (formatted in JSON), which looks something like this:

```
let rawString = reportJSON.rawString(.utf8, options: .prettyPrinted)!
let newParams = ["report": rawString]

APIHelper.shared.session.request(endPoint,
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: newParams,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```

`print(rawString)` looks like this in the Xcode console:

```
...
 "remarks" : "Door is broke. It’s time to fix this door’s handle.",
...
```

Webserver raw log shows the single quotes `'` are incorrectly parsed:

```
 ...
 "remarks" : "Door is broke. ItÆs time to fix this doorÆs handle.",
 ...
```

But then I did a test by I manually writing a string:

```
var rawString = "{\"someKeyValue\": \"It's another string with apostrophe's.\"}"
```

Web server correctly receives and prints:

```
 {"someKeyValue": "It's another string with apostrophe's."}
```

So is something is funky with my `reportJSON.rawString()` object? Is it sending something up to the server that is different than what is printed in my Xcode console log? Or could it be the webserver?

Comment: I'm guessing that the webserver is having trouble with the `’` character. Note that the `’` character ([Unicode U+2019](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)) is not the same as the `'` character ([Unicode U+0027](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)), the one you tried in your test. If you tried your test instead with the `’` character, you might see the same problem of it being converted to `Æ`.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler You're correct, I didn't notice they were actually different characters. I tested manually again and the server is indeed logging the weird character as expected.

Comment: Yep, I'm guessing the webserver is either storing the logs incorrectly, or maybe they're stored fine but just displaying it to you incorrectly.

Comment: Or yeah, the problem could be in your `rawString` method, which I only just now noticed is a method you've implemented. Maybe update your question with the code for that method so we can take a look at it?

Comment: `rawString` is a `SwiftyJSON` function which returns a `String?` value from a `JSON` object. It looks to be valid and accurate in this case.

Comment: Ahh okay. Yeah in that case my guess is the problem lies on the webserver.